# c# truthy and falsy values

Tags: c#, .net

In JavaScript there is the idea of truthy and falsy values.

e.g.

- 0 : Always false
- 1 : Always true
- '0' : Always true
- '1' : Always true

Is there an equivalent list of truthy and falsey values in the C# language on the .NET framework?

The reason I would like to know this is that I find myself doing the following

```
if(obj != null)
{
   // Do something with the object
}
```

When I could write the following

```
if(obj)
{
   // Do something with the object
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

C# only has literal `true` and `false` values.

C# requires you to be very explicit in your declarations. This behaves like other popular strongly-typed languages, as opposed to JavaScript which can do implicit conversions when needed.

It should be noted for clarity that "strong typing" is not the reason why C# doesn't implicitly convert to "truthy/falsy" values. The language intentionally is trying to avoid the pitfalls of some other compiled languages like C where certain values can be truthy, like '`0`' or '`1`' which could allow you to make a syntactical mistake you might not notice until runtime when your code behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: -1; there are a few issues here. Firstly, you're misusing the term "literal" in your first sentence; an expression which is not a literal can still be a boolean (e.g. `1 == 1`). Secondly, the claim that nothing is truthy or falsey except booleans is false, as covered by other answers here. Thirdly, the start of your third paragraph doesn't make much sense. A lack of implicit conversion is the *definition* of strong typing (or at least the most common one - it's a somewhat nebulous and overloaded term); you are effectively saying that strong typing is not the reason for itself, which is odd.

Comment: I think your comment isn't quite accurate. The expression you gave as an example (`1 == 1`) is using an equality operator. That operator internally returns a literal `true` or `false` value and there's no implicit truthy or falsy conversion happening there. Other answers don't contradict my answer. Those others show how _operators_ can force an **explicit** conversion.

You're correct that my answer was phrased confusingly so I've edited it to hopefully clarify what I intended to say.

Answer (score 39):

By default, C# only provides `true` and `false`.

However, you can have your own custom types becomes "truthy" and "falsey" by implementing the `true` operator. When a type implements the `true` operator, instances of that type can be used as a boolean expression. From section 7.19 of the [C# Language Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc):

> When a boolean expression is of a type that cannot be implicitly converted to bool but does implement operator true, then following evaluation of the expression, the operator true implementation provided by that type is invoked to produce a bool value.
>
> The `DBBool` struct type in §11.4.2 provides an example of a type that implements operator true and operator false.

Here is a code snippet of a declaration of the `true` operator (which will probably accomplish what you wanted to do in your question):

```
public static bool operator true(MyType myInstance)
{
    return myInstance != null;
}
```

If you implement the `true` operator, then you must implement the `false` operator too.

Comment: This is the correct answer. All of the answers that fail to mention operator true/operator false overloads are somewhat incomplete. It's also correct that what the OP is trying to do isn't really a good idea, but this is the best way to do it.

Comment: If you implement the true operator, then you must implement the false operator too. -> that's weird. Shouldn't the result of the false operator always be not(true operator)??!

Comment: It seems to me that it would be generally preferable to implement an implicit conversion to bool rather than the `true` and `false` operators, no? One method instead of two, and no possibility of making a mistake where the two methods are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: @MarkAmery C# language has nullable value types. For example with nullable Booleans, the expression a != b is not necessarily equal to !(a == b) because one or both of the values might be null. You have to overload both the true and false operators separately to correctly handle the null values in the expression. Another example is Double.NAN. **According to The IEEE 754 floating point standard**, comparing NaN with NaN will always return false. Comparing it to another value will also always return false. Double.NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan I think you are confused. Neither implicit conversion to bool nor `true(...)` or `false(...)` operators will get invoked when you do `a == b`, and I can't see how NaN is relevant here at all. As for nulls, an implicit conversion to bool can handle them just as well as `true(...)` and `false(...)` operators can, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/913623/1709587.

Comment: @MarkAmery My comment was a response to David's question **Shouldn't the result of the false operator always be not(true operator)??! ** but instead of his name, I tagged your name. Sorry about tagging mistake but there should not be anything wrong in what I write because I copied it directly from [Microsoft .NET docs.](http://example.com) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/true-false-operators.

Answer (score 16):

The correct answer to your question is found in section 7.19 of the C# 3.0 specification, which you can easily find on the internet.  For your convenience, the relevant text is:

> 7.19 Boolean expressions
>
> A boolean-expression is an expression
>   that yields a result of type bool.
>
> The controlling conditional expression
>   of an if-statement [...] is a
>   boolean-expression. [...]
>
> A boolean-expression is required to be
>   of a type that can be implicitly
>   converted to bool or of a type that
>   implements operator true. If neither
>   requirement is satisfied, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> When a boolean expression is of a type
>   that cannot be implicitly converted to
>   bool but does implement operator true,
>   then following evaluation of the
>   expression, the operator true
>   implementation provided by that type
>   is invoked to produce a bool value.

There are no types other than bool itself which are implicitly convertible to bool via a built-in conversion, but of course, user-defined implicit conversions to bool can be defined by the user.

Answer (score 14):

Code like that will (and should) fail to compile. If you specifically want to override that behavior, you can create an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.80).aspx) to boolean. Something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo me) {
        if (me == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true; // maybe add more logic before saying True
    }
}
```

I would call that a bad practice because, to a coder not familiar with your project, it's not immediately clear what logic feeds the boolean conversion. The more idiomatic way to do this would be to explicitly tell the reader what your code is doing, like the built in String class does, with a static helper function:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str){
    // ...
}
```

Code is only written once, and read often; optimize for readability.

Comment: +1(00000 if I could) for mentioning readability and understandability. Implicit logic in too many places can kill projects.

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer:**

In C#:

- true : Always true
- false : Always false

Everything else is not a boolean value.

Comment: Not true. See my answer below.

Comment: My answer doesn't contradict yours. Types can implement implicit conversions to bool or your 'true' operator, but any value of such a type is still not of type 'bool' :)

Comment: Hold on - I take that back. There is a difference between a boolean and a boolean expression.

Answer (score 3):

The if statement evaluates something that can be converted to / equates to / returns boolean, or a boolean itself... checking for null like obj != null is one such expression,

'if (obj)' can work if only if obj is able to convert to bool, not if it is null.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are correct. However, I have an extension method that I use in some rare cases:

```
public static bool IsTruthy(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj is DBNull)
        return false;

    var str = obj as string;
    if (str != null)
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) && 
            !str.Trim().Equals(bool.FalseString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(obj) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    catch { }

    if (obj is BigInteger)
        return ((BigInteger)obj) != 0; 

    return true;
}
```

Some notes about this:

- This method is inconsistent with how javascript handles the string "False"
- This method returns true for empty enumerables, which is consistent with javascript

Comment: `that I use in some rare cases`. Can you give some examples of when you've needed to use Truthy, Falsey checks in C#. I've never heard of anyone needing this in the .Net world ever.

Comment: I can't remember and searching my code folder turned up nothing. It does seem hard to imagine, but I'm sure I had my reasons. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you consume user-provided string-based settings or environment variables, it's nice to have a flexible definition for boolean values.  In addition to things like comparing against `FalseString`, we include "Y" and "Yes", etc (though I realize that extends beyond the original question comparing to JS' truthiness).

Comment: An example where this would be useful is implementing your own JSON parsing code or building your own template engine.

Comment: @Shiva Late reply but the only use (but consistent) for me is command-line arguments and config parameters with a single-value.  I don't ask CLI users to type out "true", I accept "1, t, T, true, True" and in some cases "OK, on (vs. off), enabled".  The 2nd list I don't call "truthy", I call that one "enabled values" list.

Comment: I lost my own `IsTruthy` implementation :/ ... but similar as with Shiva's comment, I use it to parse a setting value that could be nearly anything.  Usually boolean, sometimes a date, string value, number, or even JSON.  If it's NullOrWhiteSpace it's falsey, if it's 0 it's falsey, etc.  User-Input "Setting Parsing" essentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own truthy and falsy by means of extension methods.

```
public static bool Falsy(this object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return true;
        if (obj is string)
            if(obj as string == string.Empty) return true;
        if(obj is byte)
            if((byte)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is sbyte)
            if((sbyte)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is short)
            if((short)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is ushort)
            if((ushort)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is int)            
            if((int)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is uint)
            if((uint)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is long)
            if((long)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is ulong)
            if((ulong)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is float)
            if((float)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is double)
            if((double)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is decimal)
            if((decimal)obj == 0) return true;
        if(obj is IEnumerable<object>)
            if((obj as IEnumerable<object>).Count<object>() == 0)
                return true;
        if(obj is Array)
            if(((Array)obj).Length <= 0)
                return true;
        if(obj is ObjectId)
            if(((ObjectId)obj).Pid == 0) return true;
        if(obj is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<M>)
            if(((ObservableCollection<M>)obj).Count <= 0) return true;
                return false;
}

public static bool Truthy(this object obj) {
   return !Falsy(obj);
}
```

So you can do something like:

if(customerList.Falsy()) { throw new Exception("Cannot be null or empty."); }

Answer (score -1):

If `obj` is a type that you created, you can define a user defined implicit conversion to `bool`.

Comment: I wouldn't either!  This is the only way I know of to get the syntax Alex is asking for.

Comment: -1 because, while this is correct and was even a useful contribution at the instant it was posted, another answer fleshed out the point more in detail just 4 minutes after you posted this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/913623/1709587) and so this no longer adds any value to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Posting my two cents for checking truthy / falsy values. Also works with collections and enumerables (not thoroughly tested though...):

```
    public static bool IsFalsy(this object obj)
    {
        // null is always considered falsy
        if (obj == null) return true;

        // when obj is value type, consider it falsy when it is equal to its default value
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        if (objType.IsValueType) return Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), obj);

        // further checks for additional types
        if (obj is string s) return s == string.Empty;
        if (obj is System.Collections.ICollection o) return o.Count == 0;
        if (obj is System.Collections.IEnumerable e) return !e.Cast<object>().Any();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, $"Unsupported type {objType.Name}. Considering result as falsy.");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsTruthy(this object obj) => !IsFalsy(obj);
```

Answer (score -7):

C# is a statically-typed language, that is to say that the type of objects matter in setting what it is.

For example, "4" != 4.

JavaScript, however is a dynamically-typed language, so the types have little importance.

So in JavaScript, "4" == 4.

The "truthy" values are values that just happen to satisfy x == true, while the "falsey" values do not.

Without type safety, certain features such as overloading will yield unpredictable behaviors.

For more info, you can see [here](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/csharp/.-net-type-safety.html).

Comment: No, static Vs dynamic typing has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I know I'm eleven years late to this one, but just to be clear, this answer is *completely* wrong. The truthy values in JS are *not* the ones that compare equal to true! `if(2==true)` will take the *alternative* ("else") branch; `if(2)` will take the *consequence* branch. Is this weird? Yes. But that's the rule, and it has been the rule since we first standardized JS. The real rules are: when doing `if(x)`, x being undefined, null, nan, zero, false and the empty string are treated as false; all others are true.

Comment: When doing `if(x==true)`, the rules are: if x is true, its true. If x is false, it's false. Otherwise, this is evaluated as though you had written `if(x==1)`.